# New-AzureWebsite PowerShell Cmdlet creates website but throws Invalid URI The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to automate creation of an Azure Website and am using the following PowerShell command:

```
New-AzureWebsite -Git -Location "West US" -Name mynewsite -PublishingUsername myuser
```

It creates the website just fine, but at the end it throws the following error:

```
New-AzureWebsite : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureWebsite -Git -Location "West US" -Name crmp-ebb-uat -PublishingUsername ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureWebsite], UriFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.NewAzureWebsiteCommand
```

I can just ignore this error, but it seems messy. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

UPDATE: This error seems to be related to the -Git parameter. If I leave off the -Git parameter, it succeeds without the error. With the -Git parameter, even though I get the error, the Git repository is still setup correctly. Since there doesn't seem to be a way to setup the Git repository outside of the New-AzureWebsite cmdlet, I still have to live with this error.

Comment: If you make that call and pass -Debug to it you can view each execution step.  I've been able to repro the Exception by my error message was "Value cannot be null" and parameter name of "parameters.ServerFarm". What versions of the PS Cmdlets are you using?

Comment: I ran it with -Debug and it output a ton of diagnostic info and XML, though nothing stands out. Not sure how to sanitize this output for public posting, however.

Comment: Any idea how to check version?

Comment: At a PS command prompt: (Get-Module Azure).Version

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version (0.8.14) and the problem still exists.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? could you please share it:)

Comment: I never did solve it. I've since moved on to other projects, but last I checked, there was a try...catch around the command.